# Exit console application in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to know how to exit the console application in Nim.

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us some code. Some applications ends by themselves, some are holded in `while` loops so you have to end them with Ctrl-C or similar, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the quit function from system module, like

```
quit(1) # where 1 is the error code
1.quit() # same as above
```

or

```
"Error message".quit(0) # where 0 is the error code
```

Read more about the [detail quit](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#quit%2Cint) function
or the [shorthand quit](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#quit%2Cstring) function on nim doc